# Eclipse Window builder Pro: Adding lists etc?

Tags: java, list, user-interface, windowbuilder

When using window builder pro is it necessary to use a container for each time you wish to add a list etc? e.g. do you need to add a container to put the list into?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about pro version or not or if I'm understanding your question correctly or not. But if your talking about lists in windowsbuilder, you don't need to place them in a particular container besides of course the main frame your working on. You need at the very least a frame though.

EDIT: But if you want your gui to be flexible/resizable you might wanna think about using layouts to make it resize in a reasonable way. If your making a fixed size program then it doesn't matter much I guess.